# Gitfs remote state not recognized on highstate

Tags: salt-stack, gitfs

I have a remote state called `logstash_forwarder` that is located at `https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/logstash_forwarder-formula.git`.
Im using `git` as `fileserver_backend`.

When I run `state.highstate`, it does not find the state.

When I run `state.sls logstash_forwarder`, it works.

Why does it not work for `state.highstate`?

/etc/salt/minion:

```
master: localhost
id: lemp
file_client: local
state_events: false
environment: development

grains:
  roles:
    - lemp

file_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/salt/base
  development:
    - /srv/salt/development
    - /srv/salt/base
  production:
    - /srv/salt/production
    - /srv/salt/base

pillar_roots:
  development:
    - /srv/pillar/development
  production:
    - /srv/pillar/production

fileserver_backend:
  - roots
  - git

gitfs_provider: gitpython

gitfs_remotes:
  - https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/logstash_forwarder-formula.git
```

/srv/salt/base/top.sls:

```
development:
  '*':
    - system
    - util
    - project
    - logstash_forwarder

  'roles:lemp':
    - match: grain
    - php5
    - nginx
    - mysql
    - laravel5_app
```

Thanks in advance, have a nice day :)

Comment: What constitutes "does not work?" Doesn't run at all, or runs with errors?

Comment: It does not find the state definition, so it does not run. I' ll edit the wording

Answer (score 0):

Remove `environment: development` from your minion config.

Comment: Oh I thought it's mandatory. Im going to try it this night. Thanks already :)

Comment: How do I specify the enviroment in that case?

Comment: The places a minion matches in your top file determines the environment